# How to test the state of a button within an info window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

When I click on a marker, I display an info window with two input fields and one button:
When I close the info window I would like to know if the button was pressed or not.
How can I do it ?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i],"click", function()
    { 
        html = "Name: " + "<input type='text' id='name' />";
        html += "Firstname: " + "<input type='text' id='firstname' />";
        html += "<input type='button' id='okButton' value='OK' />";
        infoWindow[i].setContent(html);
        infoWindow[i].open(map,marker[i]);    
    });  
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow[i],'closeclick',function ()
    {  
        //action when the ok button was pressed or not
        //this code doesn't work
        $('#okButton').button().click(function()
        {
            //action
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.on()` to observe the click-event of the marker(Note: you can't attach the event directly, because the button is only available after the domready-event of the infowindow has been fired).

```
$(document ).on( "click", "#okButton", function() {
  $(this).data('clicked',true);
});
```

....it set's a `data`-property for the button, you may retrieve it later to determine if the button has been clicked:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow[i],'closeclick',function (){  
    if($("#okButton").data('clicked')){
      alert('do something');
    }
});
```

Comment: like this ?: $(document).ready(...).on(your proposition) No alert in closeclick for me !!

Answer (score 0):

`$('#okButton').button().click(function()` this is not the right way of handling the click event. Also, you're dynamically adding the button the DOM.. Replace that as

```
$(document).on('click', '#okButton', function() {
    //action
});
```